# Symfony2 Customize the Form from the Simple Registration Tutorial

Tags: php, symfony, user-registration

I've followed the [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html) and gotten the registration working just fine.

The only issue I have with this is the Form has a title:

> User

I do not want this title. I want to customize this. How do I change this title.

As for code everything is as in the [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html) except my controller which is:

```
/**
     * @Route("/SignUp", name="wx_exchange_signup")
     * @Template("WXExchangeBundle:User:signup.html.twig")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * User sign up - Open to public
     * Creates new users based on information they provide
     */
    public function signupAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'))
        {
            // redirect authenticated users to homepage 
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wx_exchange_default_index')); 
        }

        $registration = new Registration();
        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), $registration, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('wx_exchange_signup_create'),
        ));

        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }
```

Comment: Actually what do you mean by title User ??

Comment: The form is rendered with a label: `<label class="required">User</label>`. I don't know why it's rendered or how to change that.

Comment: Is `WXExchangeBundle` the name of your bundle or an extenal bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I finally found is to only display the form elements that you want:

```
<form action="/app_dev.php/SignUp/create" method="post" name="registration">
        <div id="registration">
            <div>
                <div id="registration_user">
                    <div>
                        {{ form_label(form.user.email) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.user.email) }}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{ form_label(form.user.username) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.user.username) }}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{ form_label(form.user.password.password) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form.user.password.password) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form_label(form.terms) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.terms) }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <button name="registration[Sign Up]" id="registration_Sign Up" type="submit">Sign up</button>
            </div>
            {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is documented in the Symfony [forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand) chapter.